# OR clause in where conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hi i am trying write the query where i need data for three different dates so i am writing the query below like this but i am not able fetch the data correctly

```
SELECT tr_name
FROM RT_TRANSAPORT RT
WHERE
(RT.TR_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy'))
OR
(RT.KM_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy'))
OR
(FU.TY_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy'))
OR
(FU.AT_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

please tell me where it went wrong

Comment: What do you expect (or want) and what do you get? Your query will return a list of tr_name's without any additional information. Try to get a single "between" condition correct (omit the condition for KM,TY and AT initially). The between condition includes the borders. But since upper == lower, that doesn't add too much. Maybe it'll be better to test something like `TRUNC(RT.TR_DATE, 'DD") = TO_DATE('08/11/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`.

Comment: hi @Ronald thanks for update ,But here user will pass the dates ex from date '7/11/2021' and to '08/11/2021' so between these two dates i need to fetch for each type date columns there i am facing the issue.

Comment: What does "not able fetch the data correctly" mean? Are you getting too many rows? Too few? Rows completely unrelated to the dates? No rows at all? An error even maybe?

Comment: HI @ThorstenKettner i am not getting any error but no data is coming ,is there anywhere i am doing wrong in the query

Comment: After formatting, it looks like all pair of dates have same start and end. So the dates must be exactly `08/11/2021`.

Comment: Please, provide sample data (as DDL and insert statements) and desired output for this sample data.

Comment: @SalmanA yes if dates are same or if dates are different. Then also i need to show the data with multiple or conditions

Comment: `somedate between date '2021-11-08' and date '2021-11-08'` is the same as `somedate = to_date('2021-11-08 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')` because Oracle's date is a misleading name for `datetime` datatype. Seconds are part of `date` datatype.

Answer (score 2):

To start with: while Oracle calls the data type `DATE`, it is actually a datetime, i.e. it consists of a date part and a time part. The time part can be set to 00:00:00, which can be considered the day at midnight or the day regardless of time. This means that this is subject to interpretation.

You have a column called `TR_DATE`. Are you storing dates only (i.e. time set to 00:00:00)? Or is this a misnomer (and should rather be called tr_datetime)? If you actually store a datetime, then

```
rt.tr_date BETWEEN DATE '2021-11-08' AND DATE '2021-11-08'
```

will only retrieve rows with a time set to midnight exactly and neglect all other rows at that date. A datetime '2021-11-08 00:00:01' will already get dismissed.

In order to deal with this we usually look at dates thus:

```
rt.tr_date >= DATE '2021-11-08' AND rt.tr_date < DATE '2021-11-09'
```

which gets us the complete '2021-11-08', no matter if you store time parts or not.

You say that your query gets a from date and a to date. Hence:

```
rt.tr_date >= :from_date AND rt.tr_date < :to_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type that **always** has the components year, month, day, hour, minute and second. Quite often client applications will only display the year-month-day components but the time components are still always there (even if you aren't shown them).

If you are storing a `DATE` with a time component then you need to match the entire time range for the day and can do this using:

```sql
SELECT tr_name
FROM   RT_TRANSAPORT RT
WHERE  (    RT.TR_DATE >= TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
        AND RT.TR_DATE <  TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
OR     (    RT.KM_DATE >= TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
        AND RT.KM_DATE <  TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
OR     (    FU.TY_DATE >= TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
        AND FU.TY_DATE <  TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
OR     (    FU.AT_DATE >= TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
        AND FU.AT_DATE <  TO_DATE('08/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

or

```sql
SELECT tr_name
FROM   RT_TRANSAPORT RT
WHERE  (    RT.TR_DATE >= DATE '2021-11-08'
        AND RT.TR_DATE <  DATE '2021-11-08' + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
OR     (    RT.KM_DATE >= DATE '2021-11-08'
        AND RT.KM_DATE <  DATE '2021-11-08' + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
OR     (    FU.TY_DATE >= DATE '2021-11-08'
        AND FU.TY_DATE <  DATE '2021-11-08' + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
OR     (    FU.AT_DATE >= DATE '2021-11-08'
        AND FU.AT_DATE <  DATE '2021-11-08' + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using TRUNC function,

sample,

```
TRUNC(RT.TR_DATE)
```